# Can't load old game in My Boy Premium (Emulator save)

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green, my-boy

I am facing an issue in My Boy emulator (PREMIUM) to load my last save (Emulator save). I was playing Pokemon Fire Red in My Boy Emulator and after some time I saved the game with the emulator save (or the save option that My Boy emulator has provided (not the actual fire red save option)).

Then after some time when I tried to access the game in My Boy emulator, it didn't show any game and when I checked on save folder of My boy, it was only showing Pokemon Fire Red.st04, Pokemon Fire Red.st09 files with some ss  and I can't load game with that so I converted one of the them in .gba files then also it didn't work and when I try to add that file in My Boy Emulator. The app always crashes I can't load any game.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have specified the question as my way and it is clearly written about what is my problem

Comment: Do you still have access to your original .st04 file and Pokémon Fire Red.gba rom?